# iOS Reusing Methods - can this only be done with condition?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods

I am trying to reuse a method in my code which works if there is no condition like this:

```
-(void) declareWebView
```

I can call it later like so within any other method:

```
[self declareWebView];
```

but if I want to add a condition to it (i think that is what it is called) like so:

```
-(void) declareWebView:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

How do I then use it in the `[self declareWebView];` ??

It gives me an error if I do the following:

`[self declareWebView];` or `[self declareWebView:];` //Second has the Column added to it.

Any would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to create a new method that implements the same code as the previous one this is my solution.

```
- (void) originalMethod{
    [self originalMethodWithNumber:nil];
}


- (void) originalMethodWithNumber:(NSNumber*) newNumberParam{
    NSNumber *numberValue = newNumberParam;
    if (numberValue == nil) numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];//default value.
    // Perform anything here that you were doing. replacing out the new parameter
}
```

then you can still call your legacy "originalMethod" and now have a new method with a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass a value for every argument:

```
[self declareWebView:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait duration:1.0];
```

I recommend doing some reading — [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) is a good introductory guide.